# Something is resetting my opendkim files (KeyTable and SigningTable)

Tags: ubuntu, opendkim

Something is regularly resetting my /etc/opendkim/KeyTable and /etc/opendkim/SigningTable files.

I have to manually re-edit them and restart opendkim every time...

How to find out what is resetting them and how to stop it?

Comment: I have no experience with opendkim, but just to clarify, what happens when you manually restart opendkim? Does this result in your /etc/opendkim/KeyTable and /etc/opendkim/SigningTable files being overwritten? Also, what times are we dealing with here by "regular"? Is it every few hours/ every few days/ every few weeks? Just trying to figure out if there's some sort of pattern to how often it happens.

Comment: Indeed, they are being overwritten. As for the pattern, I'm not sure exactly, I think it's daily but I need one or 2 more more days to be sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been happening to me as well.  Did you ever determine why?

Comment: And, by any chance are you using Mail-in-a-box?